# Можно ли записать в textContent значение другой переменной? (другая переменная является строкой)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть переменная var - "personName". Значение переменной - строка. Как это значение можно записать в .textContent?

Comment: document.getElementById("element").textContent =personName ;

Comment: Предыдущий комментарий ответил на вопрос?)

Comment: `$('.textContent').text(personName);`

Answer (score 2):

можно`
  Иван Иванов

```js
var personName="Вася Пупкин";
var text = document.querySelector('.test');
alert("Был: "+text.textContent);
text.textContent=personName;
alert("Стал: "+text.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Иван Иванов 
</div>
```

`